# Print the names of the sections headers of an elf file

Tags: c, elf

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8  e_ident[16];
  uint16 e_type;
  uint16 e_machine;
  uint32 e_version;
  uint32 e_entry;
  uint32 e_phoff;
  uint32 e_shoff;
  uint32 e_flags;
  uint16 e_ehsize;
  uint16 e_phentsize;
  uint16 e_phnum;
  uint16 e_shentsize;
  uint16 e_shnum;
  uint16 e_shstrndx;
} Elf32Hdr;

typedef struct
{
  uint32 sh_name;
  uint32 sh_type;
  uint32 sh_flags;
  uint32 sh_addr;
  uint32 sh_offset;
  uint32 sh_size;
  uint32 sh_link;
  uint32 sh_info;
  uint32 sh_addralign;
  uint32 sh_entsize;
} Elf32SectHdr;

#pragma pack(pop)

{
  FILE* ElfFile = NULL;
  char* SectNames = NULL;
  Elf32Hdr elfHdr;
  Elf32SectHdr sectHdr;
  uint idx;

  // ...

  // read ELF header
  fread(&elfHdr, 1, sizeof elfHdr, ElfFile);

  // read section name string table
  // first, read its header
  fseek(ElfFile, elfHdr.e_shoff + elfHdr.e_shstrndx * sizeof (sectHdr), SEEK_SET);
  fread(&sectHdr, 1, sizeof sectHdr, ElfFile);

  // next, read the section, string data
  SectNames = malloc(sectHdr.sh_size);
  fseek(ElfFile, sectHdr.sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
  fread(SectNames, 1, sectHdr.sh_size, ElfFile);

  // read all section headers
  for (idx = 0; idx < elfHdr.e_shnum; idx++)
  {
    const char* name = "";

    fseek(ElfFile, elfHdr.e_shoff + idx * sizeof sectHdr, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&sectHdr, 1, sizeof sectHdr, ElfFile);

    // print section name
    if (sectHdr.sh_name);
      name = SectNames + sectHdr.sh_name;
    printf("%2u %s\n", idx, name);
  }

  // ...
}
```

I am trying to print all the names of the sections header but there is something I don't understand. Why do we need to use :
fseek(ElfFile, elfHdr.e_shoff + elfHdr.e_shstrndx * sizeof (sectHdr), SEEK_SET);
and not just
fseek(ElfFile, elfHdr.e_shoff, SEEK_SET);
I'm just a little confused cuz I don't why it has to be elfHdr.e_shoff + elfHdr.e_shstrndx * sizeof (sectHdr) whereas elfHdr.e_shoff indicate the start of the start of section headers

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need to use

To read *section headers* (which are fixed-length records), you need to `fseek(..., elfHdr.e_shoff, SEEK_SET)`.

But that's not where the *names* (variable-length strings) are.

To read *strings*, you need to read the header for a *particular* (`shstrndx`) section (so you know where to find its contents), and then read the *contents* of that section. Which is exactly what this code does:

```
  // first, read its header
  fseek(ElfFile, elfHdr.e_shoff + elfHdr.e_shstrndx * sizeof (sectHdr), SEEK_SET);
  fread(&sectHdr, 1, sizeof sectHdr, ElfFile);

  // next, read the section, string data
  SectNames = malloc(sectHdr.sh_size);
  fseek(ElfFile, sectHdr.sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
  fread(SectNames, 1, sectHdr.sh_size, ElfFile);
```

**Update:**

> so why do we need to multiply?

In `shstrndx` you have the *index* of the section in which strings reside. Suppose this index is 17. So you want to read the contents of 17th section.

To get to the `0`th section header, you need to seek to
 `elfHdr.sh_offset + 0*elfHdr.e_shentsize`.

To get the `2`nd section header, you need to seek to
 `elfHdr.sh_offset + 2*elfHdr.e_shentsize`.

To get the `17`th section header, you need to seek to
`elfHdr.sh_offset + 17*elfHdr.e_shentsize`.

To get to `shstrndx`th section header, you need to seek to
`elfHdr.sh_offset + elfHdr.e_shstrndx*elfHdr.e_shentsize`.

P.S.

Multiplying by `sizeof(sectHdr)` is technically incorrect -- you should multiply by `elfHdr.e_shentsize` instead.

This doesn't matter in practice -- I've never seen a machine on which `e_shentsize != sizeof(sectHdr)`, but such a machine *could* exist.

Comment: so why do we need to multiply?  I know it goes somewhere but where exactly. that's what i don't understand . can you explain that in more details plz?

Comment: @FaroqAl-Nadhari I've updated the answer.